# Delay between two expect in TCL

Tags: tcl, expect

I am writing a script to automate the ambari server installation.
I have created on tcl script to automate ambari-server setup. My issue is at one place it downloads and installs jdk and that step takes a little time and meanwhile the other sends under other expects starts popping up on screen and screws up all the installation.

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sudo ambari-server setup

expect "OK to continue"
send "y\r"

expect "Customize user account for ambari-server daemon"
send "y\r"

expect "Enter user account for ambari-server daemon (root):"
send "root\r"

expect "Enter choice (1):"
send "1\r"

expect "Do you accept the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement"
send "y\r"

expect"Enter advanced database configuration"
send "y\r"

expect "Enter choice (1):"
send "3\r"

expect "Hostname (localhost):"
send "localhost\r"

expect "Port (3306):"
send "3306\r"

expect "Database name (ambari):"
send "ambari\r"


expect "Username (ambari):"
send "ambari\r"


expect "Enter Database Password (bigdata):"
send "password\r"

expect "Proceed with configuring remote database connection properties"
send "y\r"
```

after accepting Oracle Binary Code License Agreement it downloads and installs jdk and in that duration it starts taking send of next excepts.

Can someone suggest me how to stop the execution of an except while the previous one is still running.
i did try to use after and sleep to try something but it did not work.
Thanks

Comment: why would somebody downvote this? How come it is not a good enough question to put? I did share my code, I did write what I tried. if you are putting so much effort in downvoting kindly leave reason why you did that.

Comment: I found a temporary fix by putting set timeout long enough to install jdk. If still someone can suggest better solution, it would be really great.

Comment: Can you show output of installation sctipt when download and installation of jdk going and ending?

Answer (score 1):

altering the `timeout` is the right way to do it. I'd write:

```
expect "Do you accept the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement"
set old_timeout $timeout    ;# remember the previous value
set timeout -1              ;# disable the timeout
send "y\r"

expect"Enter advanced database configuration"
set timeout $old_timeout    ;# restore the timeout
send "y\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing handlers for what to do if an expected string is not received. It would be good style to add those. Otherwise the script will just continue if the string was not received within the allotted time (10 seconds by default), as you have seen.

To use a different timeout for one expect command, you can simply use the -timeout option. For example to allow 10 minutes for the jdk to install:

```
expect -timeout 600 "Enter advanced database configuration"
send "y\r"
```

And with an added handler in case of failure:

```
expect {
    -timeout 600
    "Enter advanced database configuration" {
        send "y\r"
    }
    default {
        error "jdk failed to install in time"
    }
}
```